# Not able to create text file inside the folder in phonegap

Tags: cordova

I am working on code to create text file inside the directory.

I googled and found this code on device ready.

But it is not working.

I also used **fileSystem.getDirectory** instead of **fileSystem.root.getFile**.

**Code:**

```
function gotFS(fileSystem) {
    // create dir
    alert("jjßß")
    fileSystem.root.getFile("newDir", {
        create: true,
        exclusive: false
    }, gotDirEntry, fail);
}

function gotDirEntry(dirEntry) {
    // create file
    dirEntry.getFile("newFile.txt", {
        create: true,
        exclusive: false
    }, gotFileEntry, fail);
}

function gotFileEntry(fileEntry) {
    fileEntry.createWriter(gotFileWriter, fail);
}

function gotFileWriter(writer) {
    writer.onwrite = function (evt) {
        console.log("write completed");
    };
    writer.write("some sample text");
    writer.abort();
}

function fail(error) {
    console.log(error.code);
}
```

Comment: Is this for iOS by any chance? If so: you just can't write into the app bundle.

Comment: mean can you please explain more

Comment: I need too create a folder in which i need to create text file

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following code:

```
window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, function (fs) 
{
    var fullPathtowrite = fs.root.fullPath; //this is the "working" directory for saving files
}
```